# How to remove special character(\\\) from a string in java

Tags: java

I wish to remove `///` from a string in Java.
How do I do that?

The string looks something like this:

```
String str="CHOICE(IS_PRESENT(\\\"CLIP\\\") ADD_CFS(\\\"SL6\\\") REMOVE_CFS(\\\"SMS\\\"))";
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  `String::replace`?

Comment: What do you want the string to be after the operation?

Comment: What do you mean by remove ? what is the output wanted ? Is the input always the same ? What have you tried so far ? What problem are you facing ? what difficulties are you having ? Why a simple `String.replace()` is not good in your case (I supposed you're a good person and do not ask a question that could be simply resolved by browsing the doc) ? Etc... Your question lacks of so much information to be clear and good for this site... Please edit it and show us at least all I've ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String ans=str.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

Comment: hi manoj challenge is triple slash gets automatically gets converted to single slash

Comment: CHOICE(IS_PRESENT(\"CLIP\") ADD_CFS(\"SL6\") REMOVE_CFS(\"SMS\"))

Comment: This is the sample output, I am getting in eclipse => CHOICE(IS_PRESENT("CLIP") ADD_CFS("SL6") REMOVE_CFS("SMS"))

Comment: its working for me